# Error on aggregation when using SUM in update statement in SQL 2012

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the below query. I get this error when I execute it. Could you please help understand how else could I do the comparison with SUM(REVENUE).

***An aggregate may not appear in the set list of an UPDATE statement.***

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT DIV,
           PRODUCT,
           CUSTOMER,
           REVENUE,
           REVENUE_TYPE,
           MAX(REVENUE) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT,CUSTOMER) AS MAX_REVENUE,
    FROM TABLE)
UPDATE CTE
SET REVENUE_TYPE = CASE 
                            WHEN REVENUE = MAX_REVENUE                        THEN 'High'
                            WHEN (MAX_REVENUE-REVENUE) < (0.1 * SUM(REVENUE)) THEN 'High'
                            ELSE 'Low'
                            END
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `SUM(REVENUE)` supposed to represent here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should also calculate the SUM inside the CTE

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT DIV,
           PRODUCT,
           CUSTOMER,
           REVENUE,
           REVENUE_TYPE,
           MAX(REVENUE) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT,CUSTOMER) AS MAX_REVENUE,
           SUM(REVENUE) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT,CUSTOMER) AS SUM_REVENUE
    FROM TABLE)
UPDATE CTE
SET REVENUE_TYPE = CASE WHEN REVENUE = MAX_REVENUE                       THEN 'High'
                        WHEN (MAX_REVENUE-REVENUE) < (0.1 * SUM_REVENUE) THEN 'High'
                        ELSE 'Low'
                   END
```

Answer (score 2):

You can add in the CTE another column for the sum of `REVENUE` and use it in the update statement:

```
WITH CTE AS(
    SELECT DIV,
           PRODUCT,
           CUSTOMER,
           REVENUE,
           REVENUE_TYPE,
           MAX(REVENUE) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT, CUSTOMER) AS MAX_REVENUE,
           SUM(REVENUE) OVER (PARTITION BY PRODUCT, CUSTOMER) AS SUM_REVENUE
    FROM TABLE
)
UPDATE CTE
SET REVENUE_TYPE = CASE 
  WHEN (REVENUE = MAX_REVENUE) OR ((MAX_REVENUE - REVENUE) < (0.1 * SUM_REVENUE)) THEN 'High'
  ELSE 'Low'
END
```